# Need help with sources in the field of language identity

Tags: resource-request, online-resources

I am about to write a term paper for a German "TESOL" certificate in Germany.

The term paper is about whether "there is a connection between the point in time at which the national language was learned and one's own linguistic identity? (e.g. whether the language was learned as L1 or L2).

So what I wanted to do is to investigate the language identity of migrants from different countries in Germany (England, US, Poland, Syria, China, etc.). They have all learned German as adults (older or younger). First see whether it makes a difference whether they learned it in their early 20, late 20s or early 30, etc.
And then possibily compare it with a L1 group of Germans.

I wanted to make them draw language portraits and interview them.
A language portraits (Sprachenportrait) is basically a shiloutte - used as an instrument - in which they can draw their language abilities /identity.
The interview then is about getting more details from the participants about their education, language learning in general, positive/negative experiences with languages, etc.

What I am kind of missing is literature.
Who are the leading experts about language identity in the linguistic field?

Thanks for any advice! (The termpaper is supposed to be 10 pages (sources/annex not included).